# How to avoid flex items have same height on collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

There are some elements that come from array, then I need them to get placed in a list with a diplay flex, my problem is I added a button that should collapse the selected one but others get their height modified aswell...

Have tryed with diferent display and placing inline on li elements but nothing works.

Any way to have elements in a list inline and heigh independant?

```css
.dragscroll {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.rectangle-holder {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <ul class="dragscroll">
          <li class="rectangle-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <p>Hello</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#comment1" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="collapse" id="comment1">
                  <p>Collapsable!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="rectangle-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <p>Hello</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#comment2" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="collapse" id="comment2">
                  <p>Collapsable!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="rectangle-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <p>Hello</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#comment3" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="collapse" id="comment3">
                  <p>Collapsable!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="rectangle-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <p>Hello</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#comment4" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="collapse" id="comment4">
                  <p>Collapsable!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="rectangle-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <p>Hello</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#comment5" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="collapse" id="comment5">
                  <p>Collapsable!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="rectangle-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <p>Hello</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#comment6" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="collapse" id="comment6">
                  <p>Collapsable!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="rectangle-holder">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <p>Hello</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#comment7" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="collapse" id="comment7">
                  <p>Collapsable!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add css property **align-items: flex-start;**.
It defines the default behaviour for how flex items are laid out along the cross axis on the current line. And **flex-start** set cross-start margin edge of the items is placed on the cross-start line.

```
.dragscroll {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```